# Filter a list of dates (as string) older than x days

Tags: c#, datetime

Below is the code which is getting the date and filling it into list ,how can i get the days list which is more then 5 days old from today's date.

```
List<DateTime> fileDate = new List<DateTime>();
for (int i = 0; i <= countofdifffile; i++)
{                        
    fileDate.Add(DateTime.ParseExact(fileListfordiff[i].Substring(22, 8), 
                                     "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`linq` solution

**Older than 5 days**

```
List<DateTime> fileDates = fileListfordiff 
        // parse your list into usable Dates
        .Select(x => DateTime.ParseExact(x.Substring(22, 8), "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
        // filter the list by age older than 5 days ago
        .Where(x => x < DateTime.Now.AddDays(-5))
        // return a List<DateTime> i.e file dates
        .ToList();
```

**Younger than 5 days ago**

```
List<DateTime> fileDates = fileListfordiff 
        // parse your list into usable Dates
        .Select(x => DateTime.ParseExact(x.Substring(22, 8), "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
        // filter the list by age < 5 days ago
        .Where(x => x > DateTime.Now.AddDays(-5))
        // return a List<DateTime> i.e file dates
        .ToList();
```

Comment: I want the list of date which is more then 5 days old,if i take the exam of today's date 20171229 then i want the list of dates which is post 20171225

Comment: @RahulSingh you contradicted your self in the same sentence . "more then 5 days old" - means greater than 5 day ago. "dates which is post 20171225" means less than 5 days ago

Comment: @RahulSingh Updated

Comment: i have made it adjusted and it worked for me thanks for your help .

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to do

```
List<DateTime> fileDate = new List<DateTime>();
for (int i = 0; i <= countofdifffile; i++)
{                        
    var dt = DateTime.ParseExact(fileListfordiff[i].Substring(22, 8), 
                                 "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    fileDate.Add(dt);
    fileDate.Add(dt.AddDays(-5)); // Adds 5 days less date.
}
```

Comment: I want the list of date which is more then 5 days old,if i take the exam of today's date 20171229 then i want the list of dates which is post 20171225.